# GUI with JFormDesigner displays empty window

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make a design for a simple loggin form using JFormDesigner but I'm having trouble displaying what I've made. I searched around other topics here but couldn't get a solution for my code. I tried to analyze what's missing but to no avail. It's also my first time using this designer and it's a bit different than IntelliJ's swing and I can't seem to understand everything that's going on.

```
public class Login extends JFrame {
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void loginButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO add your code here
        Operations operations = new Operations();
        try {
            String usernameStr = usernameField.getText();
            String passwordStr = passwordField.getText();
            String userTypeStr = userType.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (operations.isLoggedIn(usernameStr, passwordStr, userTypeStr, this)) {
                new Dashboard().setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please type correct Username/Password.");
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please type correct info.");
        }
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
        // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - unknown
        frame1 = new JFrame();
        label3 = new JLabel();
        label2 = new JLabel();
        label4 = new JLabel();
        usernameField = new JTextField();
        label5 = new JLabel();
        passwordField = new JTextField();
        label6 = new JLabel();
        userType = new JComboBox<>();
        loginButton = new JButton();
        closeButton = new JButton();

        //======== frame1 ========
        {
            frame1.setBackground(new Color(225, 85, 113));
            var frame1ContentPane = frame1.getContentPane();
            frame1ContentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout(
                "hidemode 3",
                // columns
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[87,fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[99,fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[95,fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[83,fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[36,fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[0,fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]" +
                "[fill]",
                // rows
                "[]" +
                "[]" +
                "[]" +
                "[]" +
                "[]" +
                "[]" +
                "[]" +
                "[]" +
                "[]"));

            //---- label3 ----
            label3.setText("Login Form");
            label3.setFont(label3.getFont().deriveFont(label3.getFont().getStyle() | Font.BOLD, label3.getFont().getSize() + 12f));
            label3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            frame1ContentPane.add(label3, "cell 0 0 44 1");

            //---- label2 ----
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/lock.png")));
            label2.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            frame1ContentPane.add(label2, "cell 0 1 45 1");

            //---- label4 ----
            label4.setText("Username");
            label4.setFont(new Font("Tw Cen MT", Font.PLAIN, 17));
            frame1ContentPane.add(label4, "cell 3 3 4 1");
            frame1ContentPane.add(usernameField, "cell 8 3 34 1");

            //---- label5 ----
            label5.setText("Password");
            label5.setFont(new Font("Tw Cen MT", Font.PLAIN, 17));
            frame1ContentPane.add(label5, "cell 3 5 4 1");
            frame1ContentPane.add(passwordField, "cell 8 5 34 1");

            //---- label6 ----
            label6.setText("Login as");
            label6.setFont(new Font("Tw Cen MT", Font.PLAIN, 17));
            frame1ContentPane.add(label6, "cell 3 7 4 1");

            //---- userType ----
            userType.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] {
                "Admin",
                "Sales Representative"
            }));
            frame1ContentPane.add(userType, "cell 8 7 34 1");

            //---- loginButton ----
            loginButton.setText("Login");
            loginButton.addActionListener(e -> loginButtonActionPerformed(e));
            frame1ContentPane.add(loginButton, "cell 3 8 39 2");

            //---- closeButton ----
            closeButton.setText("Close");
            frame1ContentPane.add(closeButton, "cell 3 10 39 3");
            frame1.pack();
            frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(frame1.getOwner());
        }
        // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
    }

    // JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - unknown
    private JFrame frame1;
    private JLabel label3;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JLabel label4;
    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JLabel label5;
    private JTextField passwordField;
    private JLabel label6;
    private JComboBox<String> userType;
    private JButton loginButton;
    private JButton closeButton;
    // JFormDesigner - End of variables declaration  //GEN-END:variables

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Login GUI = new Login();
                GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                GUI.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code is generated mostly by the designer and I've addes the main method. Could be great if you lend a hand.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to go through the swing tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) and start to manually create your code. This will give you a better understanding on how everything works and will also result in maintainable and clean code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you don't see anything is because in the generated code, the contents are added to `frame1`. But your `GUI`, which is of type `Login` also `extends JFrame`, so you got confused there. You used `GUI.setVisible(true)` even though this JFrame doesn't actually contain the components that were generated.

To fix this, you have two options.

1. Don't make your `Login` extend JFrame, instead set the contained `JFrame` visible at the end of the `initComponents()` method.
2. Add all the components to the `Login` instance, meaning `this`, in the `initComponents` method, and get rid of the `frame1`. Then you can keep the main method as it is.

Comment: After explaining that my content is in frame1 I was able to understand my code a little better and was able to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: @maudderung no worries. Please make sure to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it solved your problem.